# Python: Multiply a number in a string by a constant

Tags: python, string

I am trying to multiply by a constant a series of number in a string. I have something like that:

```
my_string = 'AMOUNT="38000" AMOUNT="43000" AMOUNT="56399"'
```

I can easily do this:

```
my_new_string = re.sub('(?<=AMOUNT\=")\d+', lambda _:str(38000 *2), my_string)
```

This works, but that is not what I need.

What I need as an output as the following:

```
my_new_string = 'AMOUNT="76000" AMOUNT="86000" AMOUNT="112798"'
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to proceed? Thank you

Comment: Why did you put ``38000 *2`` into your regexp?

Comment: It is certainly possible, but IMHO it would be much better to compute the values BEFORE writing the string.

Comment: Yes, but I am just simplifying. The actual case involves a huge string coming from an xml file in which I need to multiply by 2 the values in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make a little modification:

```
re.sub('(?<=AMOUNT\=")\d+', lambda match: str(int(match.group()) * 2), my_string)
```

The object being passed into `lambda` is the `re.Match` object with number you needed.  Now you just need to extract the number with `.group()` method, convert to `int * 2` and convert back to `str`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was missing

Answer (score 2):

You can access the matching group in the lambda, as

```
re.sub('(?<=AMOUNT\=")\d+', lambda m:str(int(m.group(0))*2), my_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom function and use f-strings:

```
def splitter(x):
    key, val = x.split('=')
    return f'{key}="{int(val[1:-1])*2}"'

mystr = 'AMOUNT="38000" AMOUNT="43000" AMOUNT="56399"'

res = ' '.join(map(splitter, mystr.split()))

'AMOUNT="76000" AMOUNT="86000" AMOUNT="112798"'
```